# How to center .btn-group from twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [twitter-bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), and i found it fairly hard to center `div` which has class `.btn-group` ([link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups)). 
Usually, I use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

or

```
text-align: center;
```

to center stuff within div, but it doesn't work when inner element has property `float: left` which in this case uses for visual effects.

[http://jsfiddle.net/EVmwe/1](http://jsfiddle.net/EVmwe/1/)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

*Edited: This has changed as of Bootstrap 3. See solution for Bootstrap 3 below.*

Is adding a wrapping div out of the question?

Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/EVmwe/4/

Important part of the code:

```
/* a wrapper for the paginatior */
.btn-group-wrap {
    text-align: center;
}

div.btn-group {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
    width: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    float: left;   
}
```

Wrapping the button group within a division, and setting the div to text-align center. The button group must also be overwritten to have display inline-block and inherited width.

Overwriting the anchors display to inline-block, and float: none, would also probably work, as @Andres Ilich said.

---

**Update for Bootstrap 3**

As of Bootstrap 3, you have alignment classes (as seen in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)). You now simply have to add the `text-center` class to a parent. Like so:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/EVmwe/409/

Comment: bootstrap now has a alignment classes that save you from having to create the btn-group-wrap class: text-left, text-center, and text-right. See Alignment Classes in the Typography section http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type

Answer (score 80):

Adding `text-center` to a parent works for me (Bootstrap 3):

```
<div class="text-center">
   <div class="btn-group">
      <a href=1 class="btn btn-small">1</a>
      <a href=1 class="btn btn-small">2</a>
      <a href=1 class="btn btn-small">3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

or add "pagination-centered", example:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar pagination-centered">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href=1 class="btn btn-small">1</a>
    <a href=1 class="btn btn-small">2</a>
    <a href=1 class="btn btn-small">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely cleaner than the accepted answer. No class overwriting needed.

Comment: I believe btn-toolbar is not necessary to the point here, in case it confuses anyone.

Comment: Actually in my case having btn-toolbar parent it caused it to NOT work. Having only class="btn-group pagination-centered" was my solution.

Answer (score 9):

for bootstrap 4

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">text 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">text 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Just declare your button links as `inline-block` instead of `float:left` and your `text-align:center` declaration will work, like so:

```
.btn-group a {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EVmwe/3/

Answer (score 6):

Since Twitter Bootstrap 3 there is no need for any workaround. Just specify the `text-align: center` for the parent element.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone also wants to change the width of the .btn-group, you can do min-width rather than width.  I did this:

HTML:

```
<div class="text-center">
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">1</button>
    <button class="btn">2</button>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-group {min-width: 90%;}
.btn {width: 50%;}
```

That set the btn-group width to 90% of text-center and each included button is 50% of the button group (45% of the text-center div).

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 3, you just need to structure as simple as following change

```
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button onclick="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                Click 1                                     
            </button>           
            <button onclick="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                Click 2
            </button>
            <button onclick="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">                                               
                Click 3
            </button>
            <button onclick="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                Click 4
            </button>
            <button onclick="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                Click 5
            </button>
            <button onclick="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                Click 6
            </button>
        </div>
    </div
```

And amend the style only this (override the bootstrap) which force float left so that you cannot force by margin or text center:

```
.btn-toolbar .btn-group {float:initial;}
```

This works for me, without much change.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following solution.

```
<div class="center-block" style="max-width:400px">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Accept</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"> Reject</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="btn-group mx-auto" role="group">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Button 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Button 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw the btn-group in a p tag and use text-align:center style for p {}

```
    p {
    text-align: center;
    }

    <p>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me in Bootstrap v3.3

```
.btn-group {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```