# How can I center this div in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to build a website.

I don't understand how to center a `<div>` that is within another `<div>`. I believe I should be able to use `-offset` to accomplish this but when it is not in an even number than surely it is never going to be possible to center it exactly, or is there another way?

I need to center the `<div>` containing the gender at http://www.bootply.com/TdcsIiUhFe

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can center that filed in a grid with odd number of columns.

**Option 1**

Enlarge the container to 4 column, the field to two and you can center it with the grid system

**Option 2**

Just use CSS:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -82px;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a width and add margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto. You don't need bootstrap for this per se.

Answer (score 0):

**Jack**, Here is a way to center a div within a another div.
Even when your parent div is using a odd number in Bootstrap col-lg-X.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt3weq02/)**.

[image: odd col-xs-X width]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.block {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkorange;
}  
.block2 {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
} 
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;  
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container col-lg-12"><br><br></div>
    
    <div class="container col-lg-12">

          <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-3 col-md-7 col-lg-5 block">
              
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-3 block2 center">
                </div>
              
          </div>
         
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'text-center' helper class on your container div.
 If the inner container is a block container, set it to:
    `display: inline-block;`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Answer (score 0):

you need this to center the btn-group
[How to center .btn-group from twitter-bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853815/how-to-center-btn-group-from-twitter-bootstrap)